# Java Structured Method Chaining

Tags: java, object, methods

A bit of a question on working with objects in java.  Suppose I have the following class.

```
public class Example {

    private String ex1 = new String();
    private String ex2 = new String();
    private int varOne;

    public Example logicOne(/*Input variables*/) {
        // Do logic
        return this;
    }

    public Example logicTwo(/*Input variables*/) {
        // Do logic
        return this;
    }

    public int subLogicOne(/*Input variables*/) {
        return varOne;
    }

    public int subLogicTwo(/*Input variables*/) {
        return varTwo;
    }

    public int subLogicThree(/*Input variables*/) {
        return varThree;
    }
}
```

I know that setting a methods type to the class name and using **return this** will allow me to chain methods when calling the class object like so.

```
Example obj = new Example;
obj.logicOne("inputOne").logicTwo("inputTwo");
```

But how would I restrict which methods could be called?  For example making **logicOne** and **logicTwo** mutually exclusive and restricting **subLogicOne** to **logicOne** and **subLogicTwo** to **logicTwo** with **subLogicThree** being shared between them like this.

```
Example obj = new Example;

obj.logicOne("inputOne").subLogicOne("subInputOne");
obj.logicTwo("inputTwo").subLogicTwo("subInputTwo");

obj.logicOne("inputOne").subLogicThree("subInputThree");
obj.logicTwo("inputTwo").subLogicThree("subInputThree");
```

Comment: You should probably have different `Example` subclasses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use interfaces to divide up the methods.

```
// you can probably come up with better names, taking your real situation into account
interface Logicable {
    SubLogicOneAble logicOne(/*same input variables as logicOne*/);
    SubLogicTwoAble logicTwo(/*same input variables as logicTwo*/);
}

interface SubLogicThreeAble {
    int subLogicThree(/*same input variables as subLogicThree*/);
}

interface SubLogicOneAble extends SubLogicThreeAble {
    int subLogicOne(/*same input variables as subLogicOne*/);
}

interface SubLogicTwoAble extends SubLogicThreeAble {
    int subLogicTwo(/*same input variables as subLogicTwo*/);
}
```

Then, you can let callers create instances of `Example` via a factory method that returns `Logicable`, rather than `new Example()`. This way, the first methods that callers can call are only `logicOne` and `logicTwo`, unless they explicitly cast to `Example`, of course.

```
class Example implements SubLogicOneAble, SubLogicTwoAble, Logicable {
    private Example() {}

    // could also consider putting this in Logicable and calling it newLogicable (?)
    public static Logicable newExample() {
        return new Example();
    }
```

```
Example.newExample().subLogicOne() // compiler error
```

Notice also that I changed `logicOne` and `logicTwo` to return `SubLogicOneAble` and `SubLogicTwoAble` respectively. This is to ensure that callers can only call certain methods on the return values of those methods (again, unless they explicitly cast). The signatures in `Example` should be changed to agree with the interfaces:

```
public SubLogicOneAble logicOne (/*Input variables*/){
    // Do logic
    return this;
}

public SubLogicTwoAble logicTwo (/*Input variables*/){
    // Do logic
    return this;
}
```